# How to make an image not display depending on position of the mouse above/below x=y line?

Tags: javascript, display, equation

Basically my website looks like this right now: https://manhattan.superhi.com/ and I would like to be able to access the bottom layer triangle that is covered by a transparent square artboard of the top triangle. The goal is to make it work like this: [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HucQr.png)

I'm not sure how to incorporate the y=x line equation into the code and set the display to 0. I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Do you use JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified example:

The span will be displayed when the mouse goes to the top left. Of course this is meant to show you the "math" and not meant to be an exact solution.

```js
// Get Elements from HTML
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const span =  document.querySelector('span');

// When ever the the mouse moves within the element you want, here, the div.
div.onmousemove = function clickEvent(e) {
      // e = Mouse click event.
      var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect(); // Get the bounding rectangle for the element

      // position within the div = (e.clientX - rect.left), this
      // position has its origin point in the top left. We can make the 
      // origin in the center by subtracting half to width aand 
      // height from the left x and y respectively
      var x = (e.clientX - rect.left) - (rect.width / 2);
      var y = (e.clientY - rect.top) - (rect.height/ 2);  
      
      // Here we check if mouse is in the top left "triangle" of 
      // the square element, where, -position.x > position.y.

      // change this to get different "triangles"
      if(-x > y) {
        span.style.opacity = '1'
      } else {
        span.style.opacity = '0'
            }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: white; /* try type yellow */
  color: #323232;

  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0; /* top element starts off as hidden */
  pointer-events: none; /* Important so that the mouse event can "go through" the top element */
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<span></span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm still not sure though how to incorporate the y=x line into the equation, especially that it's two lines going through 2 different squares... would you mind expanding on it?

Comment: Sure, we have the x and y position for the cursor in the element with the origin (0, 0) located in the center of the element. The x = y line is the diagonal going from the bottom left to the element to the top right. If we were to check if the cursor is *ON* the x = y line, then the second element will only appear if the cursor is exactly on that on pixel line, this is not what you want I’m assuming. What you want is if the cursor is greater than the x = y like or above the x = y line. We can know if the cursor is in the triangle above the x = y line by checking if -x > y.

Comment: You can have your original image be a square and the. Red triangle be another square div that is masked by a triangular HTML SVG element. You can then apply this function to the original image and control the opacity of the red image. To have it show red when the mouse is above the x = y line through the original image

Comment: I don’t know if I have understood your question properly, if I have not then i am sorry. I will delete the answer

Comment: I just don't fully understand what is happening in the code you gave me to be honest... What I'm intending to do is to check whether y / x is less than or greater than 1 and see which triangle the mouse is over. Then need to add display: none;  or opacity: 0, so one of the 4 triangles that the mouse is above is not displaying and showing the red background. Thank you so much for your help Faraz!!